# How do I add .animate to my html?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-animate, collapsable

I have this html

```
 <div class = "theListItem" data-role="collapsible-set" data-collapsed="false">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="a">
        <h3>$11.48   -  10/31/2012   -   Duane Reade #14410  -  Brooklyn Ny</h3>
        <div data-role="controlgroup"  data-type="horizontal">
          <a class= "green" href="categorize.html" data-transition="slide" data-role="button">Yes</a>
          <a class="red" href="#" data-role="button">No</a>
          <a class= "blue" href="IDontKnow.html" data-transition="slide" data-role="button">I don't know</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And it collapses content when clicked.  I want to add an animation to it so it slowly opens?  I assume I use `.animate` ?

I have tried:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.theListItem').click(function(){
           $('.controlgroup').animate({height: 100%,), 500};
     });
});
```

Comment: $('document').ready(function(){
    $('.theListItem').click(function(){
        $('.controlgroup').animate({height: 100%,), 500}
        });
});

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `.controlgroup` cause that `class` does **not exist**. 
Use the attribute selector `[]`

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/eduhiv/1/edit)**

```
$(function(){
    $('.theListItem').click(function(){
           $('[data-role="controlgroup"]', this).animate({height: 'toggle'}, 500);
     });
});
```

Or also:

```
$('[data-role="controlgroup"]', this).slideToggle(500);
```

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/eduhiv/2/edit)**

Comment: Sorry for disappearing.  That seems to work when I click one of the buttons below but I want it to toggle when I click the collapsible link, so I tried this 
$(function(){
    $('.theListItem').click(function(){
           $('[data-role="collapsible"]', this).animate({height: 'toggle'}, 500);
     });
});
but no dice.  THanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mind to explain which one is the collapsible link? cause here works really fine: http://jsbin.com/eduhiv/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.theListItem').click(function() {
        $('.controlgroup').slideToggle(500);
    }
}
```

I guess you want to have such a sliding-effect - You should use slide, if you want to slide ;).